# How to find certain tags within selected text JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to check whether there is a certain tag within selected text using JavaScript.  Essentially, its too determine whether to unbold text if it is already bolded (this is a learning project so I am not going to use an existing WYSIWYG text editor).

So, basically, I have a contenteditable 'div' then another div off to the side with buttons to style the font.  Here is that HTML code:

```
<div class = 'edit_menu'>
<a id = 'b' title = 'Bold'><image class = 'icon' src = '../images/icons/bold.jpeg' id = 'bold'></image></a><br>
<a id = 'i' title = 'Italicize'><image class = 'icon' src = '../images/icons/italicize.jpeg' id = 'italicize'></image></a><br>
<a id = 'u' title = 'Underline'><image class = 'icon' src = '../images/icons/underline.jpg' id = 'underline'></image></a><br>
</div>
```

My JavaScript (only for the bold function):

```
document.getElementById('b').onclick = function() {
   if (window.getSelection().rangeCount != 0)
   {
       var select = window.getSelection();
       var selection = select.getRangeAt(0);
       if (selection.contains(selection.getElementsByTagName('b')))
       {
            getElementsByTagName('b').parentNode.removeChild(getElementsByTagName('b'));
       }
       else {
            var selectedText = selection.cloneContents();
            var span = document.createElement('b');
            span.appendChild(selectedText);
            selection.insertNode(span);
       }
    }
 };
```

The error that Chrome is throwing back is:

```
Error: Object [Object Range] has no method getElementsByTagName
```

So, I guess I need to add something to the end of the range?

Comment: contenteditable's bold feature already toggles bold on and off with the same arguments, so you don't need to do this. In fact, the native behavior nicely handles cases where some things are bold and some aren't, or where only part of a tag is selected. You really don't want to have to re-invent and debug that stuff... If you have a range, look into  .startNode or maybe .extractContents().

Comment: @dandavis sorry, I don't understand.  Are you saying that you can toggle bold without js or...

Comment: are you not using document.execCommand in your editor? and yes, [crlt]+[b] does toggle bold selections in some browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to JS, what is execCommand?  I've read of it but I really never understood it...

Comment: ok, if you had some deep-ingrained hatred of execCommand and a great reason to re-invent the wheel, i'd say go for it. But since you don't, stop everything and readup on that before you write another line of JS that you need not to. A wysiwyg editor in js can start with just a few lines of js, mostly to define button actions. Any more than that and you're wasting your efforts.

Comment: @dandavis thank you, I've just read up on it and it solves all my troubles!

Comment: it's a heck of a head start if nothing else. Speak from experience to a self-describe noob, you REALLY don't want to dig around range objects and try chopping up partially selected text nodes, trust me on that. cheers!